# MarkLogic search: find all hits in a single document

Tags: full-text-search, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to use the `search:search` function in MarkLogic to find all hits in a single XML document.  So far, I can only get `search:search` to return one hit per document.  The function `cts:search` returns multiple hits within a single document, but without the added features that `search:search` adds to the results.
How do I set up the options to `search:search` to return all the hits in a single document?

To restrict the search to a single document, I am using the `search:options`:

```
declare variable $options :=
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <additional-query>
    <cts:document-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
      <cts:uri>/foo/bar/baz/doc.xml</cts:uri>
    </cts:document-query>
  </additional-query>
</options>;

search:search("findme", $options)
```

My cts query looks like this:

```
declare namespace cts = "http://marklogic.com/cts";
cts:search(doc("/foo/bar/bax/doc.xml")//p, "findme")
```

If I do not add the xpath "//p", I get the entire document returned.
And adding the xpath is not really acceptable, since text() is found in a quite a number of different elements.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

By default, you should actually only get one hit per document with `cts:search` and multiple snippets per doc with `search:search`. So I'd be interested to see your `cts:search` call. Perhaps you are using the `$expression` parameter?

As for modifying the snippets from `search:search`, you can [refer to customizing snippets in the documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295) to define a snippet transform to control the number of snippets per result. In particular, look at the `<max-matches>` and `<per-match-tokens>` options. [There are some examples are here.](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_50098)